# Is there an efficient way to create an image array in Javascript without having to add each individual image into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

is there a way in Javascript to access a file of many images without having to code each individual image separately?
I'm looking for something that pretty much accesses the whole folder with as little coding as possible, does it exist?
I've added a screenshot to illustrate. The images are in myImage folder and the array can be seen in the script but I'm wanting something more efficient. This is the code but there will be many more images to add

```
var URLs = [ "/myImage/2.png", "/myImage/2.png"
           , "/myImage/3.png", "/myImage/3.png"
           , "/myImage/4.png", "/myImage/4.png" ];
```

Comment: "I've added a screenshot to illustrate" where ?

Comment: Sorry, its on now